# Error in proof: Distribution of exponents for negative number

Tags: exponentiation, fake-proofs

Here are steps of the "proof":

$1=1$

$\Rightarrow 1=\sqrt{1}$

$\Rightarrow 1=\sqrt{-1\times-1}$

$\Rightarrow 1=\sqrt{-1}\times\sqrt{-1}$

$\Rightarrow 1=i\times i$

$\Rightarrow 1=-1$

At which step did things go wrong?

Comment: (ab)^0.5=a^0.5*b^0.5 only when a,b>0

Comment: @user3313320 what is the source?

Answer (score 3):

It is no longer true that
$$\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$$
when $a,b$ are not positive real numbers.

**Additional remark:** One must be careful when talking of $\sqrt{\cdot}$ in the realm of complex numbers, because it cannot be defined globally, i.e. there is no continuous function
$$f:\Bbb C\to \Bbb C.$$
such that $f(z)^2=z$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$. Formally, we define
$$\sqrt{z}=e^{\frac{1}{2}\log z}$$
where $\log$ is the [complex logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm) defined on some *proper* simply connected open subset of $\Bbb C$.

Comment: Can you provide the source?

Comment: @AmeerHamza If you are looking for a proof that $\sqrt{ab}\neq\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ you just found one! If it were true then $-1=i\cdot i=\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1}=\sqrt{(-1)(-1)}=1$. There is need to go further.